Memory Cache doesn't store keys and values as expected in ASP.NET Core app
I have a middleware that loads and writes common site data to memory cache. So far so good, but when I check if the key (and data) exists, it always returns false.
First time I run it, it's expected with no key, but when reloading the page the key isn't there and default data is written again.
Any ideas?
SetCache.cs:
public sealed class SetCache(RequestDelegate next)
{
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, IUtilityFactory utilityFactory, IMemoryCache memory)
    {
        if (!memory.ContainsKey(CommonStatics.Cached))
        {
            ICacheUtility util = utilityFactory.Get<ICacheUtility>();
            ICache cached = new Cache(httpContext);

            await cached.LoadAsync(httpContext);

            memory.Set<ICache>(CommonStatics.Cached, cached, util.CacheEntryOptions);
        }

        await next(context);
    }
}

CacheUtility.cs:
public MemoryCacheEntryOptions CacheEntryOptions => new() { SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20), AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)) };

Extension method ContainsKey:
public static bool ContainsKey(this IMemoryCache cache, string key)
{
    bool result = false;
    PropertyInfo? field = typeof(MemoryCache).GetProperty("EntriesCollection", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    
    if (field.HasValue())
    {
        ICollection? coll = field.GetValue(cache) as ICollection;

        if (!coll.Null())
        {
            foreach (var item in coll)
            {
                var methodInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty("Key");
                string val = methodInfo.GetValue(item).ToString();

                if (val.EqualStr(key))
                {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}


What do you need reflection for?

@Fildor it was a solution in another question to get the key's

And one of the GetOrCreate (sync or async version) doesn't work for you?

You cache the IHttpContextAccessor?

@Ralf no, I cache an object of type ICache

"no, I cache an object of type ICache" - which is actually a Cache that takes an IHttpContextAccessor as ctor arg ...

Surely you can just use the get API to see if a key is contained? Reflecting on non-public members is a terrible idea, and could explode at any moment. Internal changes in service patches are considered fair game, as long as the public API and behaviour don't change unexpectedly.

I changed to TryGetValue and with a little modification I think I'll get it to work.
thanks!
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, IUtilityFactory utilityFactory, IMemoryCache memory)
    {
        if (!memory.TryGetValue(CommonStatics.Cached, out ICache _)) {
            ICache cache = new Cache(httpContext);

            await cache.LoadAsync();

            ICacheUtility util = utilityFactory.Get<ICacheUtility>();
            util.SetCache(cache);
        }

        await next(context);
    }
}


Glad you solved it. But you should still think about if its a good idea how you use the HttpContextAccessor here. We can safely assume that when you put it into the constructor you keep a reference to that alive until the cache expires. So the chain Accessor->Context->Request isn't released even if being irrelevant/dead after the initial request.

@Ralf yes I'l take a look at it. I basically used it to get a service for selecting current Site element. I started with passing in the Site element, but replaced it with IHttpContextAccessor because it was easier to load the Cache object. but you're probably right so I'll make some changes
